# Any other way to style CellTables in GWT, other than ClientBundle?

Tags: java, css, gwt, gwt-celltable

Two-part question.

1)
I have absolutely nothing against [ClientBundle](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html); it's great (minification, obfuscation, etc, of the developer's input CSS), but I'm wondering, is there is another way to style a CellTable?  The obfuscated (generated) class names are used to style the table.  Is there a way (hack, or not) to turn this use of generated CSS off, and override the class names in a more direct way (say through a reference in the `index.html` file to a CSS file with the "`.cellTable*`" class names), without using `ClientBundle`?

2)
Going with the `ClientBundle` route, I see that the CSS file that overrides/replaces the default GWT CSS classes has to be referenced in code like this :

```
public interface TableResources extends CellTable.Resources {

    interface TableStyle extends CellTable.Style {
    }

    @Override
    @Source({ CellTable.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "/CellTableStyle.css" })
    TableStyle cellTableStyle();
}
```

...where `"/CellTableStyle.css"` is under the same package as `TableResources`.  Is there a way to reference a CSS file that is not in the same package as the interface, and say is in a different source directory than the base `src` dir of the project?

Comment: Did you try to specify source path (`<source path='client' />`) in your gwt.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is there a way to reference a CSS file that is not in the same package as the interface, and say is in a different source directory than the base src dir of the project?"

Just reference it in your .html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="relative/path/to/your/CSS">
```